# Button alignment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I have an app in android, where 6 `ImageButtons` must be auto aligned (equally):
3 at the top and 3 at the bottom.

I have tried this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/getting_started"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/gettingstarted" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/introduction"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/introduction" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/get_going"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/getgoing" />
```

I would like to have this in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: use a gridview with 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Make changes in image name and description according to your requirement.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/getting_started"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/gettingstarted" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/introduction"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/introduction" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/get_going"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/getgoing" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/getting_started"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/gettingstarted" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/introduction"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/introduction" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/get_going"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:onClick="imageButton6"
    android:src="@drawable/getgoing" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 LinearLayouts with orientation horizontal. These two LinearLayouts are placed within another LinearLayout with orientation vertical.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@color/Black"
android:contentDescription="@string/getting_started"
android:scaleX="0.7"
android:scaleY="0.7"
android:onClick="imageButton2"
android:src="@drawable/gettingstarted" />

 <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
android:background="@color/Black"
android:contentDescription="@string/introduction"
android:scaleX="0.7"
android:scaleY="0.7"
android:onClick="imageButton1"
android:src="@drawable/introduction" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
android:background="@color/Black"
android:contentDescription="@string/get_going"
android:scaleX="0.7"
android:scaleY="0.7"
android:onClick="imageButton3"
android:src="@drawable/getgoing" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

You can give the ImageButtons a weight of 1 and a width of 0dp, so that they automatically take 1/3 of the width.

Comment: if you give weight in this case, the image will stretch or squeeze and in the screenshot the images are centered in the screen. not fit in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

u can use something like

```
  LinearLayout [Vertical]
         |
         |
          LinearLayout [Horizontal]
                  |
                  |
                   Your 3 Buttons with weight="1"

          LinearLayout [Horizontal]
                  |
                  |
                   Your 3 Buttons with weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/getting_started"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            android:onClick="imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/gettingstarted" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/introduction"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            android:onClick="imageButton1"
            android:src="@drawable/introduction"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/get_going"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            android:onClick="imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/getgoing" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/getting_started"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            android:onClick="imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/gettingstarted"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/introduction"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            android:onClick="imageButton1"
            android:src="@drawable/introduction" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/get_going"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            android:onClick="imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/getgoing" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i used button instead of image button, you can change it to the image button

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
      >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
         android:layout_gravity="center" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
         android:layout_gravity="center" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```